# Substraction from one column to another using loop in script file

Tags: bash, shell, awk, floating-point, multiple-columns

I have the following data file. The file has 16 column. I want to subtract column $2 from each column (from $3 to $16) and save in a separate file.

```
13.85 0.545417 0.530096 0.539271 0.551338 0.555655 0.548994 0.547872 0.542829 0.537696 0.548105 0.55492 0.522208 0.54062 0.517871 0.574612
25.62 1.14902 1.10938 1.13254 1.16315 1.17326 1.15723 1.15442 1.14388 1.13291 1.15441 1.16761 1.09476 1.13889 1.09123 1.21286
44.56 2.24456 2.164 2.21009 2.27259 2.2943 2.26313 2.25812 2.23368 2.20829 2.2556 2.27972 2.13678 2.22223 2.1265 2.3646
71.36 4.07674 3.92425 4.0065 4.12716 4.16732 4.11178 4.10184 4.05272 4.00639 4.08657 4.1366 3.87901 4.0282 3.87433 4.30779
109.02 6.82479 6.55002 6.70016 6.91858 6.99698 6.88975 6.86855 6.78574 6.70263 6.82276 6.90574 6.48615 6.72953 6.47619 7.19417
160.94 10.8211 10.3596 10.6115 10.9768 11.0954 10.9379 10.8903 10.7438 10.6058 10.845 10.9637 10.2915 10.7044 10.3087 11.4487
226.64 16.1075 15.4102 15.7951 16.3518 16.5692 16.3009 16.2218 15.9761 15.7459 16.148 16.3254 15.3147 15.9319 15.3075 16.9761
290.41 21.4363 20.4612 20.9759 21.7806 22.0759 21.7127 21.6024 21.2401 20.9127 21.4066 21.6855 20.3395 21.1352 20.3578 22.5532
337.36 24.8405 23.7434 24.3358 25.3111 25.6545 25.2228 25.0429 24.5822 24.1328 24.8275 25.0746 23.677 24.5417 23.6901 26.133
```

For this, I tried to wrote the following script.

```
for (( i=3; i <= 16; i++ ))
do
paste file.txt | awk '{print $1, $i-$2}' > output/new_$i.txt
done
```

but it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Just use awk alone:

```
$ awk '{for(i=3;i<=16;i++)$i-=$2}1' file
13.85 0.545417 -0.015321 -0.006146 0.005921 0.010238 0.003577 0.002455 -0.002588 -0.007721 0.002688 0.009503 -0.023209 -0.004797 -0.027546 0.029195
25.62 1.14902 -0.03964 -0.01648 0.01413 0.02424 0.00821 0.0054 -0.00514 -0.01611 0.00539 0.01859 -0.05426 -0.01013 -0.05779 0.06384
...
```

Explained:

```
$awk '{
for(i=3;i<=16;i++)  # loop 
    $i-=$2          # subtract 2nd field from each field 3-16
}1' file            # 1 is the implicit print of record
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do want to use the method you began, you need to tell awk about the shell variable you are trying to use:

```
for (( i=3; i <= 16; i++ ))
do
paste file.txt | awk -v i=$i '{print $1, $i-$2}' > output/new_$i.txt
done
```